# Does an algorithm exist to calculate the union of two watertight meshes?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I have two watertight models (meshes). I would like to generate a mesh that represents the intersection of these two models.

Does an algorithm exist for calculating the mesh that represents the intersection of two models? If so, can you provide (high level) details of the algorithm or a reference?

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41722346/3146587) to a related problem.

For each mesh, an oracle function can be constructed that determines whether a query line segment intersects the surface (and where) as well as the location of the segment endpoints (inside / outside the solid). The two oracle functions can then be combined together to construct an oracle function for the intersection of the two solids bound by the meshes. This new oracle function can then be fed to surface meshing algorithms like Marching Cubes variants or Delaunay-based approaches (see [3D Surface Mesh Generation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html) in the CGAL documentation) to reconstruct a mesh representation of the intersection.